# Infer object's property type when access by key of specific type

Tags: typescript

I have helper type for extract keys of specific type:

```js
/**
 * From type S extract those keys that assignable to type T
 */
type KeysOfType<S, T> = {
  [K in keyof S]: S[K] extends T ? K : never;
}[keyof S];
```

**Problem**

When accessing by these keys typescript cannot infer that object property is of type T.

**Question**

It is possible to write function which accepts object and object's keys of specific without type-casts when accessing by these keys?

```js
interface EntityState<T> {
  ids: string[];
  entities: { [id: string]: T };
}

function collectIds<T>(obj: T, keys: KeysOfType<T, EntityState<unknown>>[]): string[] {
  const ids: string[] = [];
  for (const key of keys) {
    const state = obj[key];
    // TS2339: Property 'ids' does not exist on type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends EntityState<unknown> ? K : never; }[keyof T]]'.
    ids.push(...state.ids); // <-- state not inferred as EntityState<unknown>
  }

  return ids;
}

const state: {
  status: boolean;
  first: EntityState<{ value: string; }>;
  second: EntityState<{ prop: string; }>;
} = {
  status: true,
  first: {
    ids: ['1'],
    entities: {
      '1': { value: 'value from first state' }
    }
  },
  second: {
    ids: ['id_from_second_state'],
    entities: {
      'id_from_second_state': { prop: 'prop from second state' }
    }
  }
};

console.log(collectIds(state, ['first', 'second']));
```

[TypesScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgxATgewLbQC4E8AOBTaAZWjwA8NEBDAYw0wAtkBnAgazyyYcrsqaYCWAcwB2lAEYAbAhmSZcBACpRYwKNnzQA0hyYB5AGaKFAHkIAaaIoB80ALzQA3iugBtLdAEjo7LMgNEALoAXETugSTkeCIAJlyK0AD82tChIngAbniIANxQAL6uvv5BeZBQXhjZBjQEAKIiGALYhBg8eCY2Ti4CcaFMFF5CroFl0CSNzQJ4TKGObr39gyJCIVbQ%20WX5UFAGAK4itALI3tTIktK0AJJxndYAFMjiAFahipa%20s9q6hsb4nZYGk0Wm0qiYDqwRMgAO4iazWEYASiWiCGI26MGgZxEA08fWgA1RK3RDhGY2gBmQiGg92xuN80BKn0RGPG4zpdAG7XsjJeRQ4oxc42AwCshAATABmSUATlCAAUUPhENhoAByXpMNXQGLIGbQKF0MgCXEneSaNWKVzzdyebzFAKKNZWrQRMhVWJcIHNLCtdrgkSQmFwpIpNKZbI5Db8vyOwKBNUAOiFeKYiZweyY9HuidzXKqic1iKjIugJgAtOXec8YxFDXaDNlEHgYtA%20NBvSD-RCobDrC5tuVMc2MHtEN5NVsdpAOQTQXg5i585nQuJkOc8JQROSDAJEANQp3ffOTPMMpRJHsF3OiUIo-lrOSWNiYofJl2wfMcEqUUN74%20Ch5ZxMWXL4KCvcwXF3fcMEXTFxk1UJXDVABGNVAkg%20CJmBaYvmAtk2VQtU5mgc9L2vNUyKvCkUHQaDcXzPBtUHAiWI2TDxmfE5X1ZNlELcDUYgAfQMWihK42JxPndCOLZaIcJmOCCPGQSRLEiThMY4inGgb9kBwUI1T0nAaLQAk8BfOd2mYlM2MHTZpzpDdE0kZAhFpc5LgwG4mHuRjLGQ%20iMDVSw1Q09DEWLKAgA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, your function knows almost nothing about the `obj` so it cannot assume that it contains needed properties basing on the second argument. You did a great job and added a constraint for keys so now you need to add a constrain for the object.
It might be written in a more elegant way, but still:

```
function collectIds<T extends {[K in E]: S}, E extends KeysOfType<T, S>, S extends EntityState<unknown>>(obj: T, keys: E[]): string[] {
  const ids: string[] = [];
  for (const key of keys) {
    const state = obj[key];
    ids.push(...state.ids);
  }

  return ids;
}
```

[Updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.7.5&ssl=21&ssc=2&pln=13&pc=1#code/PQKhFgCgAIWgxATgewLbQC4E8AOBTaAZWjwA8NEBDAYw0wAtkBnAgazyyYcrsqaYCWAcwB2lAEYAbAhmSZcBACpRYwKNnzQA0hyYB5AGaKFAHkIAaaIoB80ALzQA3iugBtLdAEjo7LMgNEALoAXETugSTkeCIAJlyK0AD82tChIngAbniIANxQAL6uvv5BeZBQXhjZBjQEAKIiGALYhBg8eCY2Ti4CcaFMFF5CroFl0CSNzQJ4TKGObr39gyJCIVbQ%20WX5UFAGAK4itALI3tTIktK0AJJxnZFVsVzz7p7edWvE%20dCWdffRcdpdIZjPhOpZCNZwX9HtAGk0Wm0qiYDqwRMgAO4iazWAAUyHEACtQopLL5ZrCRgBKJaIIYjbowaBnEQDTx9aADWkrekOEZjaAGZCIaA45ms3zQEpkykM8bjMV0AbteySwlFDijFzjXpMAB0OD2THoON1pqVVV1Osp-O25UZiDwGD2iG8Oq2O0gCo5iLwcxc5sNoXEyHOeEoIn5BgEiAGoThzSwrXaJnmGUokj2vu9XKEOQ21n5LGZMTjkwRyfmOBQOBpQzz%20QLBRVzkZAfJFEz5hcUZjGD9jO17NcAHIAIzDwJdgcTeHTcktuVysfDubQNMZrPD9eZgUodA91nmvDDjZa0%20M-JT8ZFk4l2VynWhEe9AD6Bj3L5vsU-PonV7l0SzjM-aLuMw6vu%20aCfngxY-u0K5ONAVbIDW0DDshOC7mgHIwbe3rweei62uMtqbB6YqhrqkjIEIornJcGA3EwOJHpYI4Hhgw6WMOX4xBOlLWkAA)

`E extends KeysOfType<T, S>` (without []) gives us a `string[]` that represents all the keys in type T which values are of type S (EntityState). This type is used to construct a constraint for the first argument type: `{[K in E]: S}`.